# When removing a member of an array in firestore, the observable that I follow is updated with undefined values in the resulting arrays

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following functions. The first updates the firestore database to remove a value from an array in an db object.

```
removeGuardianFromFamily(guardian: string, familyId: string) {
    return this.afs.collection('family')
      .doc(familyId)
      .update({
        guardians: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(guardian)
      }).then(() => { // Need to remove family from guardians family doc
        return this.removeFamilyFromUsersFamDoc(guardian, familyId);
      }).catch(() => {
        return { success: false }
      })
  }
```

The next functions, get the family doc, and get the all family information (I have included the interfaces used when grabbing the data).

```
export interface FamilyInfo {
    familyId: string;
    moderatingGuardian: string;
    guardians: string[];
    okToReadKids: string[];
    familyName: string;
    kids: string[];
    isSearchable: boolean;
}

export interface FamilyInfoWithoutId {
    moderatingGuardian: string;
    guardians: string[];
    okToReadKids: string[];
    familyName: string;
    kids: string[];
    isSearchable: boolean;
}

getFamiliesDoc() {
    return this.authservice.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.collection('families')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection('myfamilies')
            .doc('myFamiliesDoc')
            .valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }));
  }

getAllMyFamilies() {
    return this.getFamiliesDoc().pipe(
      tap((familiesDoc) => console.log("This is families doc in getAllMyFamilies", familiesDoc)),
      switchMap((fdoc: FamiliesDoc) => {
        // here we fetch all family data
        let familyDataDocs = fdoc.families.map(f => {
          return this.afs.doc(`family/${f}`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map((doc) => {
              return { familyId: doc.payload.id, ...doc.payload.data() as FamilyInfoWithoutId } as FamilyInfo;
            }));
         })
        return familyDataDocs.length ? combineLatest(familyDataDocs) : of([]);
      }),
      tap((families: FamilyInfo[]) => console.log("This is families in getAllMyFamilies AFTER WITH ALL FAM DATA", families)),);

  }
```

It is in getAllMyFamilies() where I observe the problem. On the first load, the object loads perfectly, and reflects the values in the DB. However, while staying on the same page, with a change in the database, such as calling removeGuardianFromFamily(), is where the problem occurs. The object initially says:
​

```
familyName: "Day"
familyId: "famId"
guardians: Array [ undefined ]
isSearchable: true
kids: Array [ undefined ]
moderatingGuardian: "modGuard"
okToReadKids: Array [ undefined ]
```

But the observable then refires and the object appears with the arrays intact with the correct information, however at this point the front end has updated and the undefined values are the ones displaying.

I then thought, how about we check for the undefined values and explicitly set them only when not undefined. So I did the following:

```
hasUndefinedInArray(arr: string[]) {
    let hasUndefined = false;
    for (let mem of arr) {
      if (mem === undefined) {
        hasUndefined = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return hasUndefined;
  }
  getAllMyFamilies() {
    return this.getFamiliesDoc().pipe(
      tap((familiesDoc) => console.log("This is families doc in getAllMyFamilies", familiesDoc)),
      switchMap((fdoc: FamiliesDoc) => {
        // here we fetch all family data
        let familyDataDocs = fdoc.families.map(f => {
          return this.afs.doc(`family/${f}`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            tap((doc) => console.log("This is doc.payload.data() in families in getAllMyFamilies IN THE MIDDLE *******************************************", doc.payload.data())),
            map((doc: Action<DocumentSnapshot<FamilyInfoWithoutId>>) => {
              if (!this.hasUndefinedInArray(doc.payload.data().guardians)
                 && !this.hasUndefinedInArray(doc.payload.data().okToReadKids) && !this.hasUndefinedInArray(doc.payload.data().kids)) {
                let guardArray = [];
                let okToReadKidsArray = [];
                let kidsArray = [];
                for (let guard of doc.payload.data().guardians) {
                  if (guard !== undefined) {
                    guardArray.push(guard);
                  }
                }   
                for (let ok of doc.payload.data().okToReadKids) {
                  if (ok !== undefined) {
                    okToReadKidsArray.push(ok);
                  }
                }   
                for (let kid of doc.payload.data().kids) {
                  if (kid !== undefined) {
                    kidsArray.push(kid);
                  }
                }
                
                const famInfo: FamilyInfo = {
                  familyId: doc.payload.id,
                  moderatingGuardian: doc.payload.data().moderatingGuardian,
                  guardians: guardArray,
                  okToReadKids: okToReadKidsArray,
                  familyName: doc.payload.data().familyName,
                  kids: kidsArray,
                  isSearchable: doc.payload.data().isSearchable
                }
                return famInfo;
              }
            }),
            tap((familyInfo) => console.log("This is familyInfo in families in getAllMyFamilies IN THE MIDDLE AFTER *******************************************", familyInfo)),);
         })
        return familyDataDocs.length ? combineLatest(familyDataDocs) : of([]);
      }),
      tap((families: FamilyInfo[]) => console.log("This is families in getAllMyFamilies AFTER WITH ALL FAM DATA", families)),);

  }
```

This showed that the initial pull from the db was successful, and no arrays had an undefined member from the following lines:

```
return this.afs.doc(`family/${f}`).snapshotChanges().pipe(
            tap((doc) => console.log("This is doc.payload.data() in families in getAllMyFamilies IN THE MIDDLE *******************************************", doc.payload.data())),
```

However, right after this here:

```
 tap((familyInfo) => console.log("This is familyInfo in families in getAllMyFamilies IN THE MIDDLE AFTER *******************************************", familyInfo)),);
```

It is observed that the arrays in the FamilyInfo objects each have a single undefined value in them on the initial update as seen above before. Are there any strategies for getting past this?

Comment: Not sure.. but shouldn’t it be: .update(guardians: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(guardian)) - so without {}..?

Comment: Nope.. when I try that it sets off the warning: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2. Further this function works and the changes are reflected in the DB.. something is going wrong during this map: map((doc:Action<DocumentSnapshot<FamilyInfoWithoutId>>) => {
              return { familyId: doc.payload.id, ...doc.payload.data() as FamilyInfoWithoutId } as FamilyInfo;
            }));